# Можно ли поставить тире на месте пропущенного союза "потому что"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы, тире

Тире, по правилам, может замещать пропущенные члены предложения. А союзы?

- Например, *На улицу никто не пошёл — ударил мороз.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**На улицу никто не пошёл — ударил мороз.**

**Это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение).** По классическим правилам здесь должно ставиться двоеточие, так как причина указана во втором предложении (так как, потому что).

**Но двоеточие можно заменить тире.**

В этом случае  обозначается только взаимообусловленность предложений (без указания направления причинно-следственной связи), а в устной речи делается меньшая по длительности пауза.

Тогда второе предложение имеет присоединительный характер.